# Disable Windows sound card jack sensing

Tags: windows, sound-card, drivers

I have a sound card that is able to sense what jacks are plugged in where. The problem is that it keeps detecting my speakers on and off (they come and go randomly).

Last time I had this problem I checked everything (cables, velds, etc), and finally found a change I could make to the registry to disable jack sensing. It worked fine for a couple of years until yesterday when I reinstalled Windows.

Its an Asus RoG Maximus Formula motherboard with a X-Fi soundcard (came bundled with the MB).
The ASUS drivers either bluescreen or say I don't have a valid card. They are also for SoundMax, which I suspect is not compatible with Creative X-Fi?

I've tried the fix described on http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/54848-windows-headphone-plug-sensing-broken.html without any luck.

Any idea how I can disable the auto sensing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it.

- Open registry Editor with elevated privileges
- Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96C-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000\GlobalSettings`
- Change the value `EnableDynamicDevices` to zero.
- Restart your system.

Comment: +1. Very thanks. I didn't wanted to install propietary drivers - so your answer helped very much.